# How to replicate an OutlineInputBorder around a FlatButton in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a few fields taking info from a user. Some of which are TextFormFields, and others are buttons (FlatButton and PopupMenuButton). I would like to replicate the OutlineInputBorder hint style that is present around the TextFormFields to be displayed around my button fields. I've gotten pretty close:

[empty fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk0kB.jpg)

and with info inside the fields

[filled fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC2PS.jpg)

How can I make the help text of "Select Birthday" go inside the border like "First Name"? Here is the relevant code:

```java
Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(paddingStandard),
                child: TextFormField(
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person, color: colorMuted),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: colorPrimary)),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: colorMuted)),
                    labelText: "First Name",
                    labelStyle: textMuted,
                  ),
                  controller: nameController,
                  autofocus: false,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(paddingStandard),
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: colorMuted),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    child: FlatButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(paddingStandard),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          var selectedDate = await _getBirthday();
                          selectedDate ??= birthday;
                          setState(() {
                            birthday = selectedDate;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        right: paddingStandard * 2),
                                    child: Icon(Icons.cake, color: colorMuted),
                                  ),
                                  RichText(
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      text: TextSpan(
                                          text: birthday == null
                                              ? "Select Birthday"
                                              : DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy')
                                              .format(birthday),
                                          style: birthday == null
                                              ? textMuted
                                              : textDark))
                                ]),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                              color: textColorMuted,
                            )
                          ],
                        ))),
              )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the birthday button with a stack and display some text on top of the border if birthday != null.

Here is a code demo, (replace it with the birthday button container):

```
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: colorMuted),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    child: FlatButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(paddingStandard),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          var selectedDate = await _getBirthday();
                          selectedDate ??= birthday;
                          setState(() {
                            birthday = selectedDate;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.only(right: paddingStandard * 2),
                                child: Icon(Icons.cake, color: colorMuted),
                              ),
                              RichText(
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  text: TextSpan(
                                      text: birthday == null
                                          ? "Select Birthday"
                                          : DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy')
                                              .format(birthday),
                                      style: birthday == null
                                          ? textMuted
                                          : textDark))
                            ]),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                              color: textColorMuted,
                            )
                          ],
                        ))),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(50, -12),
                    child: birthday != null
                        ? Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                            color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                            child: Text("birthday"),
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks, I just gotta play around with the offset. Do you know if the font-size of the OutlineInputBorder can be changed? Or if it is specified anywhere? I need to match the style of the two

Comment: to change the theme of the label edit your theme data (or create one - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes) ```ThemeData(
  inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
    labelStyle: TextStyle(<yourStyleHere>)
  ),
),```

Comment: Yeah, I can set the style, which I did, but when it moves up into the border, it appears it shrinks by some ratio. I cannot set the size of the text in the border without changing the size of the hint text itself. I need to know the ratio (or size in general) it shrinks to when moving into the border, so I can match it with the Birthday field. Any idea what value that is, or where to find it? Or is that set in some property in TextStyle I'm not seeing?

Comment: oops, sorry, misunderstood your question. I don't know how flutter calculates the size of the label when is in the border.